# Python: Multiple conditions questions on pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a question regarding multiple-conditions on pandas columns. I have the following dataframe:

```
    A   B   C
0   0   9   0
1   1   8   0
2   1   9   0
3   1   5   1
4   1   9   1
5   1   8   1
6   -1  9   0
7   -1  5   -1
8   -1  7   -1
```

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

1.) If A>0 and B <6 C should become a 1 and keep that until A changes (B could get above 6)

2.) If A<0 and B <6 C should become a -1 and keep that until A changes (B could get above 6)

Any suggestions how to do that without a loop?

I am struggeling with how to "memorize" the status of B having been below 6 for the current A= 1 or A=-1 period.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Index B A A>0 & B >0.8 A>0 & as soon as B>0.8
2127 0.551354566 0 0 0
2128 0.66838571 0 0 0
2129 0.809306329 1 1 1
2130 0.812775762 1 1 1
2131 0.81319083 1 1 1
2132 0.814134565 1 1 1
2133 0.814281433 1 1 1
2134 0.812157799 1 1 1
2135 0.810377385 1 1 1
2136 0.808989447 1 1 1
2137 0.806981847 1 1 1
2138 0.800548453 1 1 1
2139 0.792510453 1 0 0
2140 0.785009569 1 0 0
2141 0.777099821 1 0 0
2142 0.768469301 1 0 0
2143 0.762370584 1 0 0
2144 0.754136153 1 0 0
2145 0.74586568 1 0 0
2146 0.74058505 1 0 0
2147 0.733714521 1 0 0

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.select` create your help column when satisfied your own conditions , then we do `groupby` with `bfill`

```
s1=(df.A>0)&(df.B<6)
s2=(df.A<0)&(df.B<6)
df['v']=np.select([s1,s2],[1,-1])
df.v.replace(0,np.nan).groupby(df.A).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[1023]: 
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    0
7   -1
8   -1
```

Comment: did OP want output to be float rather than int?

Comment: @pygo adding astype(int)

Comment: Many thanks Wen!! Sorry, trying to understand the code. Why would you goupby A and use ffill?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems also not to solve the issue. Here is the concrete example. Index is time.

Comment: Tried to add it but somehow the format is not readable when I copy the table here

Comment: Index B A A>0 & B >0.8 A>0 & as soon as B>0.8
2127 0.551354566 0 0 0
2128 0.66838571 0 0 0
2129 0.809306329 1 1 1
2130 0.812775762 1 1 1
2131 0.81319083 1 1 1
2132 0.814134565 1 1 1
2133 0.814281433 1 1 1
2134 0.812157799 1 1 1
2135 0.810377385 1 1 1
2136 0.808989447 1 1 1
2137 0.806981847 1 1 1
2138 0.800548453 1 1 1
2139 0.792510453 1 0 0
2140 0.785009569 1 0 0
2141 0.777099821 1 0 0
2142 0.768469301 1 0 0
2143 0.762370584 1 0 0
2144 0.754136153 1 0 0
2145 0.74586568 1 0 0
2146 0.74058505 1 0 0
2147 0.733714521 1 0 0